# Installshield - Uninstall not removing service

Tags: installshield

We're having a weird issue with Installshield.

I'm using the Installshield to install a windows service on our DEV and QUAL environment (same machine). The configuration files are identical (.isl, .isproj and .vspscc) but we are experiencing some different behavior when we do the uninstall .

When we uninstall the QUAL service (they have diferent names) is all ok, but when we unistall the DEV service, the service is not removed from the services list as well as not remove from the registry entries.

Any idea what may be causing this different behavior for identical configuration on the same machine?

Comment: Are you stopping the service in the .MSI prior to removal? As a test, You could install it, manually stop it and then do an uninstall. If it removes it ok stop the service on the uninstall event

Comment: Yes, I'm stopping the service. The really odd thing is that we are doing the same thing for DEV and QUAL but we are getting different outcomes. I've compared the .isl, .isproj and .vspscc files, I'm I missing any configuration file?

Comment: You mention they have different names. Are you mentioning the service by the correct name in both instances? (dev and qual)?

Answer (score 12):

If you expand the events section of the service you've added (components section: advanced settings, services, your service), there will be 6 events (you might need to create a new key to see these) - one of which is "Uninstall Delete". The default is no, change it to yes and you'll be good. (I also set Uninstall Stop to yes as well).

Comment: You can also access through System Configuration->Services on same (Installation Designer) tab.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but Today I have faced the same issues, service doesn't remove during uninstalling service. As **gbjbaanb** replied I just follow but I did it slightly different ways. Go to **Services** and under **Control Settings** and I followed as  **gbjbaanb** mentioned instructions.

[image]

By the way, I'm using Installshield 2014.